# Light-weight-transaction Performance in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

LWT performance is bad according to the cassandra docs. In the following scenario;

Scenario 1;

- Read from cassandra (thread 1)
- Write to cassandra if above step does not return any data (thread 2)

In this case, above steps are processed different threads. `Thread1` read data from cassandra, then pass it to the `thread2`. Then `thread1` will query for new data as soon as possible. This will increase the performance. But there will be 2 connections on cassandra.

Scenario 2;

- Write to cassandra using the LWT.

In this case, only one thread will sends query to the cassandra. If LWT performance really bad, this will reduce the overall performance.

I'm not sure which one is better. Does LWT performance really bad?

Comment: The two are not the same, in that scenario 1 will suffer a race condition, unless you are using other mechanisms to ensure threads do not process the same data, e.g. actor model.

Comment: You are right. But i guarantee only one thread will process the same key in the cassandra at the same time. I just try to imagine that what is the exatcly performance of lwt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you are providing a guarantee that the race condition between threads will not occur for the same primary key, then you should continue to use the read then write approach.

LWTs go through a 4 phase process, prepare, read, propose, commit - this can result in the process taking 4 times longer than the single operation since it requires 4 round trips between the node acting as the co-ordinator / proposer and the replicas involved in the transaction.